# h1 adds space on top of the page in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

i researched, it is a common bug, but none of the suggested fixes helps. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Rnj.jpg

HTML

```
<div id="banner">
        <h1>Paslaugos</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#banner {
width: 100%;
height: 240px;
background-image: url('img/paslaugos_bg.png');
background-position: center;
display: block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}


h1 {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight: 100;
padding-top: 80px;
line-height: 130px;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-size: 60px;
color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: left;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgb( 3, 3, 3 );
width: 1200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
```

Any ideas? The space appear even when i delete the whole css or add clear:both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The margin comes from the CSS styles the browser automatically gives those elements. It is called user agent styles. You'll have to overwrite those defaults. In your case `#banner h1 { margin: 0 auto;}` should do it.

Take a look at [Codes & Notes: Default browser styles and normalize](http://codesandnotes.com/default-browser-styles-and-normalize/) for more on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You should [reset your css](http://www.cssreset.com/). The reason is that different browsers have some different default css rules they apply to elements.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers come with pre-set values for margins and paddings for different elements, these values can differ from one browser to another, in order to get rid of this, you should reset them, in this case, add the folowing code to your h1 CSS:

```
margin:0px; padding:0px;
```

Also, there is this padding you added, the `80px` one, if you don't need it get rid of it as well.